# Using google icons in Android Application

Tags: android, icons, maps

Are developers allowed to use the default Google icons in their applications to launch Google applications from their applications?

For example if I want to allow my user to launch the Google maps application from my application, can I add an ImageView with the Google Maps icon as its resource to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Google explains use of all their imagery & such here -
[Google Permissions](http://www.google.com/permissions/index.html)